# Problem with timestamping a PDF using Java and iText

Tags: java, timestamp, itext

Im writing a app for signing and timestamping PDFs using iText and Java.
Because we (in Slovenia) have different approach for getting timestamp from our TSA (via web service, using certificate and password) I cannot use those methods from iText. I have a Perl script for this.
  So.. how, or with which parts of code can I write timestamp and digest (from a web service response) to a PDF??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not if I'm following exactly what you're asking for, but it sounds like you want to adjust the date that is reported for the signing of the PDF.

Assuming you are using PdfStamper to sign the document, after you have created the signature try

```
pdfStamper.getSignatureAppearence().setSignDate(calendar)
```

where calendar is a Calendar instance you have created using a response from your timestamp web service.

Getting iText to include TSA information along with the signature is a bit more involved.  Its a bit outside of my knowledge area, but from my understanding, you need to use an externally generated certificate, and most people do it using BouncyCastle.

This [discussion](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/TSA-in-iText-2-1-6-tt2169253.html#a2169255#none) has an example of how to do it.  You'll eventually want to be making use of [TSAClientBouncyCastle](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/TSAClientBouncyCastle.html) when getting the encrypted certificate.  This [page](http://itextpdf.sourceforge.net/howtosign.html#signtsocspjava) has an alternate example including OCSP information as well.

If you get this worked out, please add in your solution so that there's a more authoritative answer on stackoverflow.

Comment: `if I put this into my code, the pdf reader will still said that date/time are from the signer's computer.

from WS-response, I get:
"#TimeStampInfo-..."-> dsig:DigestValue (hash)
"#TimeStampAuthority" -> dsig:DigestValue (hash)

dsig:SignedInfo
-> dsig:SignatureValue (hash), dsig:X509Certificate (hash);
TimeStampInfo
-> ds:DigestValue (hash), ts:SerialNumber (long), ts:CreationTime (timestamp), ts:Nonce (long);

i need to add those values to PDF, that the reader will recognise this as TSA timestamp.
Which metods do I need to override? Can I see this deep into the code?`

Comment: Ok, I see where you are going with this now.  That's a bit outside of my knowledge area, but check the links in the answer.  They might help you, and others might be able to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example

http://itextpdf.sourceforge.net/howtosign.html#signtsocspjava

you have to replace

```
   sap.setCrypto(null, chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.SELF_SIGNED);
```

for

```
sap.setCrypto(pk, chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.WINCER_SIGNED);
```

and put these correct version of libs

```
- org.bouncycastle -> bcprov-jdk16 1.40
- org.bouncycastle -> bctsp-jdk16 1.38
```

Comment: warning: you're using the long deprecated itext version 2 with the long outdated Wincer_Signed thing!